# Struggling with authentication method

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, authentication, encryption

I want to, without using the built in WCF/c# components for it,

1. Authenticate clients to a RESTful service
2. Handle authentication failures on an API call in the client

This is a pedagogical exercise:  I realize there are built in methods for authentication, I want to do this from scratch to understand how it all works.

I have the password hashing and checking logic and an  exposed REST call that validates the password, but I am unsure how to procede from there.

#### Background

Im struggling on creating an authentication method for my rest service.

So far I have managed to create a hash of a password, salt and stored the salt and I have managed to authenticate the user. However I am not sure how you would encapsulate all of my wcf REST requests so that if any are requested (GET,POST) it asks you to login and if your logged in does not.

Because I roled my own authentication technique and I am new to web services and C# I really dont know where to begin?

So I am going to offer 300 rep to anyone who could provide an approach to this.

#### Code

This is my rest service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService
{
  .... all of my GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests
{
[DataContract(Name="Student")]
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember(Name = "StudentID")]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password;
    [DataMember(Name = "Salt")]
    public byte[] Salt;
    //note the use of public datamembers for password and salt, not sure how to implement private for this. 
 }
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
[Serializable]
public class Service: IService
{
    #region Authentication, hash and salt
    protected RNGCryptoServiceProvider random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    public byte[] GenerateSalt() //Generate random salt for each password
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[10000]; 
        random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
    public static byte[] Hash(string value, byte[] salt) //hash and salt the password 
    {
        return Hash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), salt); 
    }

    public static byte[] Hash(byte[] value, byte[] salt) // create hash of password 
    {
        byte[] saltedValue = value.Concat(salt).ToArray();

        return new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(saltedValue); //initialise new isntance of the crypto class using SHA-256/32-byte (256 bits) words  
    }
    public string AuthenticateUser(string studentID, string password) //Authentication should always be done server side 
    {
        var result = students.FirstOrDefault(n => n.StudentID == studentID);
        //find the StudentID that matches the string studentID 
        if (result != null)
        //if result matches then do this
        {
            byte[] passwordHash = Hash(password, result.Salt);
            string HashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash);
            //hash salt the string password
            if (HashedPassword == result.Password)
            //check if the HashedPassword (string password) matches the stored student.Password
            {
                return result.StudentID;
                // if it does return the Students ID                     
            }


        }
        return "Login Failed";
        //if it doesnt return login failed 
    }
    #endregion
```

I am hosting from a console app aswell and I have no web.config files or app.config files. And because I did my own authentication method I am not sure if basic authentication would work.

I also do not want to keep a session in order to keep the service SOA and Stateless.

Console app:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host opened");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Note that on my client side I do something very basic in order to authenticate:

```
    private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Authenticate user (GET Request)
        string uri = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AuthenticateUser/{0}/{1}", textBox1.Text, passwordBox1.Password);
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
        string UserAuthenticationID = xDoc.Element("string").Value;
        Int32 value;
        if (Int32.TryParse(UserAuthenticationID, out value))
        {
            MainWindow authenticatedidentification = new MainWindow(); 
            authenticatedidentification.SetLabel(UserAuthenticationID);
            authenticatedidentification.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Content = UserAuthenticationID;
        }
    }
```

So I am not sure what else would have to be carryed to the main application if anything for the above mentioned, in order for the main app to access those rest requests.

Comment: Um. You need to store the salt that's being used to generate the password hash, so you can reuse it during authentication. Are you doing that (but have removed it from your question)?

Comment: Ideally, store 3 values - whether you combine these into a single binary blob, or model them separately, you will want them - a) The version of the password code, b) The password salt, and c) The password hash. Store (a) so that, if you later need to switch to a different algorithm, you can, and can tell which users you've upgraded. Store (b) and (c) so that you can perform authentication.

Comment: ASP.NET Membership despite his name could be also used with local apps

Comment: I feel I must point out Eric Lippert's advice about writing your own Authentication module: "let me give you all my standard caution about rolling your own cryptographic algorithms and security systems: **don't**.  It is very, very easy to create security systems which are almost but not quite secure. A security system which gives you a false sense of security is worse than no security system at all!"

Comment: Adam granted you are very much right in what you say, but note for learning purposes it is good practice to understand what and how you are implementing these methods.

Comment: And if you want the service to securely pass the user/password to the service then you need to use SSL. Otherwise, you might as well just use plain text user/password.

Comment: Wow, you accept my answer, you used my answer, and then you overhaul your question (adding my answer to it) to an entirely new question.  Never answering any of your questions again totally uncool.

Comment: 1. You don't need 10000 bytes worth of salt, nor do you want that much, use like 16 or 20.  Consider using PBKDF2, see http://csharptest.net/470/another-example-of-how-to-store-a-salted-password-hash/

Comment: I believe writing a WCF behavior is the way to go, but hum... Every tentative answer to this question seems to get one or more immediate downvotes, so I won't try it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way this is typically done is

1. the client provides some credentials via an authenticate service call
2. the service validates those credentials and hands back some auth-token.
3. Subsequent calls have use that token to authenticate.

   This is done either by sending the token along (e.g. [http digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)) or way more securely,  the token is a key that is used to compute a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) on the on the paramaters. This prevents anyone from tampering with the requests.

There is a decent though long discussion on how to do this in WCF [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx). See the section on "Security Considerations" and the section on "Implementing Authentication and Authorization"

So lets say you've done this ( or your sending the username and password with every request -- a bad idea but hey, this is just for educational purposes) and you have a AuthenticateUser method that returns false if the users is not authenticated. Now in every exposed REST method you add this call ( with the parameters either being the user name and passwords, or an auth token)

```
if (!AuthenticateUser(/* auth params here */))

{

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode =

        HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

    return;
}
```

This causes the request to fail and the client will get an HTTP 403 Forbiden response.

I assume you are using HttpWebRequest to make the calls to the REST API.

So in your client program, after your have prepared request,added whatever paramaters you need, do this

```
try
{
    var wResp = (HttpWebResponse)wReq.GetResponse();
    var wRespStatusCode = wResp.StatusCode;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    var wRespStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
    if( wRespStatusCode == HttpStatusCode. Unauthorized)
    {
       // call to your sign in / login logic here
    } else{
        throw we;
    }
}
```

You need to include the authentication token somehow in the request, either as a get or post paramater or in the header. Post or Get is simply a matter of adding the paramater to the request data. The header is a little bit more difficult, I believe its outlined in the MSDN link I refrenced above.

Comment: This was a nice explanation I just wish you had incorporated my example code for it. I am also wondering why it has recieved two down votes which makes me think this isnt the correct way?

Comment: Almost everything on here has received two down-votes with no explanation and it made me suspicious. I was looking at the timing of them and the only thing I can think of is that people are down-voting each-other trying to get the bounty. Read the MSDN article, it should confirm most of what I wrote. Although its rather long, so maybe just read the referenced sections.

Comment: @JungleBoogie hey, you had a bounty on this. Is it possible you could award it somehow. Not sure if you can do it with the question closed, but you could just make another one and give me the link or something

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use OAuth or OpenID for your REST service?! There is OAuth 2.0 or prior versions. There are also implementations for client and server. OAuth pass good for REST services

You do not need to create your own mechanism.

Main site for OAuth - http://oauth.net/code/
There you can find description on how OAuth works, flows etc. Also there are links to implementations, e.g. [DotnetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)

Latest specification - [https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2)

You can find a lot of samples for DotNetOAuth's OAuth implementation on their Github repo
https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/tree/master/samples

Answer (score -1):

@jbtule and @Damien_The_Unbeliever make excellent points about storing salt with the hashed password.

As for your question of how to implement it, I would not do it as a separate service method, but instead make the authentication part of the method call itself. It will then be up to the client to pass credentials with the service call.

**[This link](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/)** describes in a lot of detail how to accomplish that, what it looks like from the server and client, etc.

Edit: Instead of passing the username and password in the message credentials like in the above link, you can pass the login token and just check that it's valid on the web service before executing the request.

Comment: Please explain the down-rating. I gave a valid answer on how to approach and accomplish web service authentication. The provided link lists code for each step of the process.

Answer (score -2):

The way I recently (last couple of weeks) did it is via an IDispatchMessageInspector. In the message inspector class I used securityContext.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets to check the client's (caller) certificate, but you can use a custom header (User,Password) and look at OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders. And in the AfterReceiveRequest( ) I would either throw a fault if the user was not a valid user or simply return null to indicate success.

Then I created an attribute that would add my inspector (MessageInspector) to the service class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var channelDispatcher = dispatcher as ChannelDispatcher;
            if (channelDispatcher != null)
            {
                foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
                {
                    var inspector = new MessageInspector();
                    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
                }
            }
        }

        //var config = new ServiceLayerConfiguration();
        //config.RequestProcessorImplementation = typeof(PassThruRequestProcessor);
        //config.Initialize();

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

And finally in the service class I would simply add the attribute.

```
[AuthorizeAttribute]
public class OperaService : IMyService
```

I can give more details if necessary. I still have the client/service app on my box. :)